# Using encryption algorithm in smart contract

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am new to **Block chain** development.I am now trying to write a smart contract in **Hyperledger Composer**. My smart contract should do this function.
It should access a file on the cloud and run an **encryption algorithm** on that file and should send to the user on **request  file** transaction invocation.I have a few questions on this:

1. Is it  possible to access a file on the cloud through smart contract code?
2. I have an encryption algorithm in Java.How can I include it in smart contract so that it can encrypt the file?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Composer Transactions allow you to 'call out' using the Node Request module, so if your cloud file system can make documents available on a REST service then you will be able to access them from Composer.  The details of calling out to a REST service are [covered here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out) in the Composer documentation.

For the encryption as with the Cloud File, if you can expose your java algorithm as a REST service then you can call it.  Otherwise you would need to re-write your encryption in javascript whilst remembering that Composer does not allow 'Import' or 'Require' in the transaction functions.